# How to change sending messages in android?

Tags: android, sms, message

I want to change text messages when they are in **sending** status.

In fact, I need to change text of message written by user before sending and add some advertisement in it (maybe add a link). How can I do so?

Is device needed to be root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't do that. You should not do that. It's very intrusive. If you want to do that, create an Sms Client of your own and do that.

Comment: User knows about it and I want it to be usable for any messaging app that user is using.